# Populating search contract results with images

Tags: c#, binding, windows-8, windows-store-apps

My search contract basically looks at an SQLite database, and returns the relevant records. These records are then manipulated so that the appropriate information is available for display and selection on the search charm page. However, I a results corresponding image to display with the result (following the default search contract result template)

The image is stored as a string in my `CustomObjectRecord` database. When the record is selected it is converted to a `CustomObject`, and the image string saved in the `CustomObjectRecord` is converted to a Bitmap object called `searchImage`. I want this to be displayed with my results, but when the search charm returns I get an error on the output console

`Error: BindingExpression path error: 'searchImage' property not found on 'My_App.Classes.CustomObject, My App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='searchImage' DataItem='My_App.Classes.CustomObject, My App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' (Name='thumbImage'); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')`

The template definition

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LocalStandardSmallIcon300x70ItemTemplate">
    <Grid Width="294" Margin="6">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,10" Width="40" Height="40">
                <Image Name="thumbImage" Source="{Binding searchImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,-10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

`searchImage` is defined in CustomObject as

```
 public Bitmap searchImage;
```

The `searchImage` property of my CustomObject is set when the record is loaded from the database. The Name binding in the same template works fine.

Any pointers would be great.
If any more code is required please let me know.

Comment: the message seems to indicate the property is not there at all versus having an issue with formats, etc.  Is the name "searchImage" supposed to be camel case?  e.g., if you changed searchImage to Name here (invalid, I know) would you get that same error?

Comment: searchImage is defined in CustomObject as I've added above. I tried putting in Name instead of searchImage in the binding and the error does not show up, though obviously the image is still blank grey. I don't understand why the image is not seen in searchImage when Name is, as they are both defined in the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it was simply a case of including `{ get; set; }` on the `searchImage` definition...

Answer (score 0):

I am not a SQLite expert but are you storing your image in Db or just the path? If the image then why not save images on localstorage and store just the path to it in Db, you then simply use ms-appdata:/// to read your images from localstorage see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx

Comment: I did it as described to keep each image together with its associated fields. To do it as you described would be possible I guess, but it would mean I have to worry about managing each image file in the local storage individually. Also, these images are uploaded by the user, not resources in the app.

Comment: I think saving on disk is a much better approach and you wouldn't run into this issue you have